# SQL Server: Transaction deadlock on SQL with PK in WHERE clause

Tags: sql-server, database, indexing, database-deadlocks, locks

We have a Java application that uses a table AU_PROCESSQUEUE for following operations:

1. INSERT new job
2. UPDATE job status to READY | RUNNING
3. UPDATE associated workflow information for that job
4. DELETE the job once it is completed

**Table DDL**

```
CREATE TABLE AU_PROCESSQUEUE (
AU_JOB_ID varchar(80) NOT NULL ,
AU_PROCESSFLOW_ID varchar (50)  NULL , 
AU_PROCESSFLOW_NAME varchar (64)  NULL ,
AU_STATUS varchar (30)  NULL ,
AU_SUBJECT varbinary (Max) NULL ,
AU_PROCESSFLOW_OBJECTADDRESS varchar (350)  NULL ,
AU_JOB_METADATA varbinary(Max) NULL ,
AU_QUEUE_TIME datetime NULL ,
AU_START_TIME datetime NULL ,
AU_END_TIME datetime NULL ,
AU_INSTANCE_ID varchar (100)  NULL ,
AU_PRIORITY numeric(18, 2) NULL ,
AU_NODE_NAME varchar (50)  NULL ,
AU_MESSAGE varchar (2000)  NULL ,
CONSTRAINT PK_AU_PROCESSQUEUE PRIMARY KEY(AU_JOB_ID)) ;
```

**INDEXES**

```
CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AU_PROCESSQUEUE_AU_STATUS_AU_NODE_NAME]
ON [AdeptiaBackend].[dbo].[AU_PROCESSQUEUE] (
[AU_STATUS] ASC,
[AU_NODE_NAME] ASC
) WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)

CREATE NONCLUSTERED INDEX [IX_AU_PROCESSQUEUE_AUQUEUETIME]
ON [AdeptiaBackend].[dbo].[AU_PROCESSQUEUE] (
[AU_QUEUE_TIME] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF,
SORT_IN_TEMPDB = OFF, DROP_EXISTING = OFF, ONLINE = ON,
ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON)
```

There is a `SELECT` query that keeps on executing on this table periodically to load the QUEUED jobs ordered by queued time

```
Select * from AU_PROCESSQUEUE (NOLOCK)  
WHERE (AU_STATUS = 'Queued' OR AU_STATUS = 'Ready To Resume') 
and 
( AU_NODE_NAME='localhost' OR AU_NODE_NAME IS NULL ) 
ORDER BY AU_QUEUE_TIME LIMIT 200
```

The Java application only process a fixed number of jobs at a time (defined as job concurrency say 60), so essentially, there are 60 different threads where following queries are being executed in parallel:

```
Update AU_PROCESSQUEUE 
SET AU_NODE_NAME=@P0 , 
AU_INSTANCE_ID=@P1,
AU_PROCESSFLOW_OBJECTADDRESS=@P2,
AU_STATUS=@P3,
AU_START_TIME=@P4 
WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P5

DELETE from AU_PROCESSQUEUE WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P0
```

**Issue**

Under high job concurrency, say 60, we are seeing transactions being deadlocked in SQL Server. Here is the deadlock trace:

```
<deadlock-list>
 <deadlock victim="process48d914ca8">
  <process-list>
   <process id="process4cdda84e8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 18:72057594055098368 (666003c8ddef)" waittime="34201" ownerId="1603282" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:31.663" XDES="0x4cdff7770" lockMode="U" schedulerid="1" kpid="3892" status="suspended" spid="122" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:31.663" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-09T10:12:31.663" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.663" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-UOEQMBQP08C" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1603282" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="132" sqlhandle="0x0200000063980b37a86688199d73e7920178af18c95d90030000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))DELETE from AU_PROCESSQUEUE WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P0            </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process48d914ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 18:72057594055098368 (666003c8ddef)" waittime="35028" ownerId="1603137" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:31.107" XDES="0x488c743b0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="2232" status="suspended" spid="286" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:31.107" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-09T10:12:31.107" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.107" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-UOEQMBQP08C" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1603137" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="132" sqlhandle="0x0200000063980b37a86688199d73e7920178af18c95d90030000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))DELETE from AU_PROCESSQUEUE WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P0            </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process4c809dc28" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 18:1:3620 " waittime="33435" ownerId="1609771" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:57.623" XDES="0x48d905770" lockMode="IU" schedulerid="4" kpid="1712" status="suspended" spid="289" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:57.623" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-09T10:12:57.620" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.620" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-UOEQMBQP08C" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1609771" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="132" sqlhandle="0x0200000063980b37a86688199d73e7920178af18c95d90030000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))DELETE from AU_PROCESSQUEUE WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P0            </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process4c7853468" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 18:1:4688 " waittime="33460" ownerId="1609641" transactionname="UPDATE" lasttranstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:57.237" XDES="0x4c77783b0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="2" kpid="5660" status="suspended" spid="326" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:57.237" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-09T10:10:20.090" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.090" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-UOEQMBQP08C" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1609641" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="220" stmtend="522" sqlhandle="0x0200000086a2ea1594021304e59bc20f346ab6be8a632b340000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000),@P1 nvarchar(4000),@P2 nvarchar(4000),@P3 nvarchar(4000),@P4 datetime2,@P5 nvarchar(4000))Update AU_PROCESSQUEUE SET AU_NODE_NAME=@P0 , AU_INSTANCE_ID=@P1, AU_PROCESSFLOW_OBJECTADDRESS=@P2, AU_STATUS=@P3, AU_START_TIME=@P4 WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P5                                                    </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process4bd316ca8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 18:72057594055098368 (666003c8ddef)" waittime="35028" ownerId="1609113" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:55.737" XDES="0x48d66a3b0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="6312" status="suspended" spid="336" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:55.733" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-09T10:12:55.733" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.733" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-7EFMLLQ3PKJ" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1609113" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="132" sqlhandle="0x0200000063980b37a86688199d73e7920178af18c95d90030000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))DELETE from AU_PROCESSQUEUE WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P0            </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process4bd316108" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 18:72057594055098368 (666003c8ddef)" waittime="35028" ownerId="1607808" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:51.910" XDES="0x4d1e4a6d0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="9144" status="suspended" spid="266" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:51.910" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-09T10:12:51.910" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.910" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-UOEQMBQP08C" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1607808" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="132" sqlhandle="0x0200000063980b37a86688199d73e7920178af18c95d90030000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))DELETE from AU_PROCESSQUEUE WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P0            </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process4bfc37468" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 18:72057594055098368 (666003c8ddef)" waittime="35029" ownerId="1604201" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:36.360" XDES="0x4b89623b0" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="2704" status="suspended" spid="535" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:36.360" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-09T10:12:36.360" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.360" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-7EFMLLQ3PKJ" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1604201" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="132" sqlhandle="0x0200000063980b37a86688199d73e7920178af18c95d90030000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))DELETE from AU_PROCESSQUEUE WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P0            </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process4bd317468" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="KEY: 18:72057594055098368 (666003c8ddef)" waittime="35029" ownerId="1603983" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:35.400" XDES="0x47ff6c540" lockMode="U" schedulerid="4" kpid="3508" status="suspended" spid="160" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:35.400" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-09T10:12:35.400" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.400" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-UOEQMBQP08C" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1603983" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="132" sqlhandle="0x0200000063980b37a86688199d73e7920178af18c95d90030000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))DELETE from AU_PROCESSQUEUE WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P0            </inputbuf>
   </process>
   <process id="process4bd3168c8" taskpriority="0" logused="0" waitresource="PAGE: 18:1:3620 " waittime="8339" ownerId="1598759" transactionname="DELETE" lasttranstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:16.410" XDES="0x491786d90" lockMode="IU" schedulerid="4" kpid="6692" status="suspended" spid="350" sbid="0" ecid="0" priority="0" trancount="2" lastbatchstarted="2018-01-09T10:12:16.410" lastbatchcompleted="2018-01-09T10:12:16.407" lastattention="1900-01-01T00:00:00.407" clientapp="Microsoft JDBC Driver for SQL Server" hostname="WIN-7EFMLLQ3PKJ" hostpid="0" loginname="sa" isolationlevel="read committed (2)" xactid="1598759" currentdb="18" lockTimeout="4294967295" clientoption1="671088672" clientoption2="128056">
    <executionStack>
     <frame procname="adhoc" line="1" stmtstart="40" stmtend="132" sqlhandle="0x0200000063980b37a86688199d73e7920178af18c95d90030000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
     <frame procname="unknown" line="1" sqlhandle="0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000">
unknown     </frame>
    </executionStack>
    <inputbuf>
(@P0 nvarchar(4000))DELETE from AU_PROCESSQUEUE WHERE AU_JOB_ID=@P0            </inputbuf>
   </process>
  </process-list>
  <resource-list>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594055098368" dbid="18" objectname="topco_cluster_bk.dbo.AU_PROCESSQUEUE" indexname="IX_AU_PROCESSQUEUE_AUQUEUETIME" id="lock4cfec4f80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594055098368">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process48d914ca8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4cdda84e8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594055098368" dbid="18" objectname="topco_cluster_bk.dbo.AU_PROCESSQUEUE" indexname="IX_AU_PROCESSQUEUE_AUQUEUETIME" id="lock4cfec4f80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594055098368">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process4bd3168c8" mode="U"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process48d914ca8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="3620" dbid="18" subresource="FULL" objectname="topco_cluster_bk.dbo.AU_PROCESSQUEUE" id="lock4af764580" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594055098368">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process4c7853468" mode="U"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4c809dc28" mode="IU" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="4688" dbid="18" subresource="FULL" objectname="topco_cluster_bk.dbo.AU_PROCESSQUEUE" id="lock4cfe98600" mode="IU" associatedObjectId="72057594055098368">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process4cdda84e8" mode="IU"/>
     <owner id="process4bfc37468" mode="IU"/>
     <owner id="process4bd317468" mode="IU"/>
     <owner id="process48d914ca8" mode="IU"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4c7853468" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594055098368" dbid="18" objectname="topco_cluster_bk.dbo.AU_PROCESSQUEUE" indexname="IX_AU_PROCESSQUEUE_AUQUEUETIME" id="lock4cfec4f80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594055098368">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process48d914ca8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4bd316ca8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594055098368" dbid="18" objectname="topco_cluster_bk.dbo.AU_PROCESSQUEUE" indexname="IX_AU_PROCESSQUEUE_AUQUEUETIME" id="lock4cfec4f80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594055098368">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process48d914ca8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4bd316108" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594055098368" dbid="18" objectname="topco_cluster_bk.dbo.AU_PROCESSQUEUE" indexname="IX_AU_PROCESSQUEUE_AUQUEUETIME" id="lock4cfec4f80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594055098368">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process48d914ca8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4bfc37468" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <keylock hobtid="72057594055098368" dbid="18" objectname="topco_cluster_bk.dbo.AU_PROCESSQUEUE" indexname="IX_AU_PROCESSQUEUE_AUQUEUETIME" id="lock4cfec4f80" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594055098368">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process48d914ca8" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4bd317468" mode="U" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </keylock>
   <pagelock fileid="1" pageid="3620" dbid="18" subresource="FULL" objectname="topco_cluster_bk.dbo.AU_PROCESSQUEUE" id="lock4af764580" mode="U" associatedObjectId="72057594055098368">
    <owner-list>
     <owner id="process4c809dc28" mode="IU" requestType="wait"/>
    </owner-list>
    <waiter-list>
     <waiter id="process4bd3168c8" mode="IU" requestType="wait"/>
    </waiter-list>
   </pagelock>
  </resource-list>
 </deadlock>
</deadlock-list>
```

**Questions**

1. Why am I seeing a deadlock when both the `UPDATE` and `DELETE` query is being executed with PK in the `WHERE` clause? Isn't updating and deleting on PK considered the best scenario?
2. Will it help if I change my PK (column AU_JOB_ID) to INT (or BIGINT) instead of VARCHAR?
3. Will it help if I change status column (AU_STATUS) to refer lookup codes - that will change the column from VARCHAR to INT and help in faster comparison and search?

I am not an expert on database and SQL Server, so any help shall be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Come on format so we don't have to scroll a mile to the right

Comment: @Paparazzi: Thank you for the suggestion, I have improved the formatting.

Comment: If you think they're "phantom" collisions, you could switch to transaction isolation level SERIALIZABLE.

Comment: Probably not a phantom collision.  When a row is deleted from the clustered index, it has to be deleted from the index on AU_QUEUE_TIME as well.  So it will seek that index for the AU_QUEUE_TIME value for the deleted row, and will need to read (with a U lock) all the index keys with the same AU_QUEUE_TIME to find the index key it needs to delete.

Answer (score 0):

Stepping back, it's going to be tough to tweak and troubleshoot your way through this problem, even if you were "an expert on database and SQL Server".  The basic problem the three different data structures that need to be updated whenever you update or delete: the clustered index and two non-clustered indexes.

When using a table as a queue, you either need to keep the table structure extremely simplistic, or use [Service Broker](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/database-engine/configure-windows/sql-server-service-broker) Queues, which is SQL Server's native in-database queuing feature.

So do what you would do in Java, synchronize access to your shared data.  In SQL Server you use a transaction and an [Application Lock](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-stored-procedures/sp-getapplock-transact-sql) to ensure that a session has brief, exclusive access to run a bit of code.

Comment: Initially, we only had PK (clustered index) on the table and in that case, the frequency of deadlock was very high. After applying the non-clustered index, it has reduced but we are still seeing deadlocks. The table doesn't have too many records - roughly around 25K.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be focused on where the locks are occurring rather that what is causing them.

If the select was not taking locks then the update and delete should not have a problem.

Comment: Are you suggesting that SELECT statements are causing the locks because of which I am seeing the deadlocks during UPDATE and DELETE operation? If yes, then why that SELECT statement is not part of the deadlock trace? Moreover, the SELECT statement is issued with NOLOCK hint - do you still see it as an issue?

Comment: NOLOCK is dangerous and not in your question as stated.  The select is not deadlocking.  Answer is only as good as the question.  Sorry I could not be of assistance.